# Convert javascript string to php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm scraping a website using php to get some data. The data I get is a valid javascript array.

```
          "['v42, 2015', 23428, 30243, 76993]
                ,
          ['v43, 2015', 24060, 30401, 73412]
                ,
          ['v44, 2015', 22855, 29720, 71573]
                ,
          ['v45, 2015', 24455, 30757, 78991]
                ,
          ['v46, 2015', 24275, 30398, 84424]"
```

I now have this string in php, but how can I convert it to a php array?

Comment: Please (re)take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried? What has you stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = "['v42, 2015', 23428, 30243, 76993]
                ,
          ['v43, 2015', 24060, 30401, 73412]
                ,
          ['v44, 2015', 22855, 29720, 71573]
                ,
          ['v45, 2015', 24455, 30757, 78991]
                ,
          ['v46, 2015', 24275, 30398, 84424]";
```

It is a valid js array if you add the proper start & end square brackets delimiter. Furthermore, to comply with the php json parser requirements, the string delimiters must be double-quoted instead of single-quoted, so a quick replacement must be done.

You then can decode it like so :

```
$ary = json_decode('['.str_replace("'",'"',$string).']', true);
```

Comment: dont know why I got `null` from your method

Comment: @swidmann likely spotted the issue, the single quotes need to be replaced with double quotes. updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes may be valid in JS, but JSON sometimes have a problem with it.
You can try it here: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

To get a valid JSON, just replace the single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`, to get an array with arrays you have to surround your string with brackets `[]`.

Try this example code:

```
$string = "['v42, 2015', 23428, 30243, 76993]
                ,
          ['v43, 2015', 24060, 30401, 73412]
                ,
          ['v44, 2015', 22855, 29720, 71573]
                ,
          ['v45, 2015', 24455, 30757, 78991]
                ,
          ['v46, 2015', 24275, 30398, 84424]";

$string = str_replace( "'" , '"', $string );
$string = '['.$string.']';

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( json_decode( $string ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the `[ ]` with `''` and then breaking the string.

```
$string = str_replace(']', '', str_replace('[', '',$string));
$array = explode(',', $string);
```